# Android - unique and constant device ID

Tags: android

I need to register user devices on server with an unique identifier that be a constant value and doesn't change in the future.

I can't find a good solution to get unique id from all devices (with/without simcard).

**[Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)**: Secure.ANDROID_ID is not unique and can be null or change on factory reset.

```
String m_androidId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**IMEI**: IMEI is dependent on the Simcard slot of the device, so it is not possible to get the IMEI for the devices that do not use Simcard.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

**WLAN MAC Address**: If device doesn’t have wifi hardware then it returns null MAC address. and user can change the device mac address.

```
WifiManager m_wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
String m_wlanMacAdd = m_wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

**Bluetooth Address string**:If device hasn’t bluetooth hardware then it returns null.

```
BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
String m_bluetoothAdd = m_BluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

**[Instance id](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)**: instance_id will change when user uninstalls and reinstalls app. and it's not a constant value.

Do you have any idea to get a unique id from all Android devices (with/without simcard, Bluetooth, ...) that really be unique, cannot be null and doesn't change after uninstall/reinstall app?

Comment: Notice that a tablet without both SIMcard and WiFi cannot exist or be remotely useful. Have you considered a combination of both?

Comment: @STTLCU no. but users can change devise MAC address.

Comment: @STTLCU I'm not sure what tablets you've got around you, but hardly anyone I know has a tablet _with_ a SIM card.

Comment: Android ID is officially designed for the purpose: http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html , which means that there are probably no better substitutes.  That it doesn't survive device wipe is deliberate.

Comment: Can I ask why the value has to stay constant even after a factory reset? If I'm selling my phone on, I sure as hell don't want anyone else to be able to access your server and get at my data. The `Secure.ANDROID_ID` seems to be ideal for this, what's your requirement that says otherwise?

Comment: You can combine all of them with an ID generated by you to make a Unique Combination. And build a pattern matching routine which will agree to identify the device if it meets some level of probability say 95% (in case one or more of them varies)

Comment: @MattTaylor probably I didn't explain myself, but what I meant that the probability to lack WiFi AND to lack a sim card in a single tablet is pretty much null. so an ID made by a combination of the two of them is guaranteed to be not null pretty much always.

Comment: @MiladNouri Why would you like to identify _device_ of each user. A user might buy a new device or lose its current device. IMO, you should identify each _user_ not their devices. Identifying users seems to be easy, for instance by their E-Mail accounts.

Comment: @MiladNouri will you mind explaining the use case. That will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that Secure.ANDROID_ID is the best choice. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. But it resets on device factory reset.

there are some reports that shows some devices has same Secure.ANDROID_ID on all instances.

we can add extra items (like sim serial, GCM instance id or ...) to the Secure.ANDROID_ID and generate new unique fingerprint.

Answer (score 3):

Mutiple users can be setup on Android device and **Secure.ANDROID_ID** is different for every user on same Android device. So using Secure.ANDROID_ID means single devices will be registered as a different device for each user setup on the device.

Comment: **ANDROID_ID** gets reset when device is factory-reset.  Thus, it is not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Secure.ANDROID_ID is your only friend. However it has some problems (empty results) on older (<2.3) devices. All other ID's do not work on all type of devices.

Please also read [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)